# Integrity control of DB2 query over network

Tags: jdbc, db2, websphere

Is there a way to control the integrity of a DB2 query/response between Websphere 6.1 and DB2 8.1 ?

I know there is a SecurityMechanism usuable with the JDBC UDB Type 4 driver to encrypt password and data. Is there something similar for integrity ?

Comment: Please explain your definition of "integrity". What's your concern here? Generally JDBC "just works".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but TCP/IP manages the integrity of the communication between sockets.

The software is built on the assumption that the communication layer will provide integrity of the message-response loop.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I'm looking for something better than the basic checksum tcp provides. SSL has a much better integrity check, but there is no SSL support on JDBC with DB2.